# $http post in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I've just started learning Angular.js. How do I re-write the following code in Angular.js?

```
var postData = "<RequestInfo> "
            + "<Event>GetPersons</Event> "         
        + "</RequestInfo>";

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (req.readyState == 4 || req.readyState == "complete") {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                console.log(req.responseText);
            }
        }
    };

    try {
        req.open('POST', 'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons', false);
        req.send(postData);
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

Here's what I have so far -

```
function TestController($scope) {
      $scope.persons = $http({
            url: 'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons',
            method: "POST",
            data: postData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.data = data; // how do pass this to $scope.persons?
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
            });

}
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">    
    <li ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.name}}</li>
</div>
```

Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In your current function if you are assigning `$scope.persons` to `$http` which is a promise object as `$http` returns a promise object.

So instead of assigning `scope.persons` to $http you should assign `$scope.persons` inside the success of `$http` as mentioned below:

```
function TestController($scope, $http) {
      $http({
            url: 'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons',
            method: "POST",
            data: postData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here 
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.status = status;
            });

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried so many solutions but headers: `{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` did the trick

Comment: Please note that the `success` and `error` functions have deprecated now.

Comment: See [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/)

Answer (score 13):

Here is a variation of the solution given by **Ajay beni**. Using the method **then** allows to chain multiple promises, since the **then** returns a new promise.

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $http({
        url: 'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons',
        method: "POST",
        data: postData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
        }, 
        function(response) { // optional
            // failed
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use $http:

[AngularJS: API: $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
$http.post(url, data, [config]);
```

Implementation example:

```
$http.post('http://service.provider.com/api/endpoint', {
        Description: 'Test Object',
        TestType: 'PostTest'
    }, {
        headers {
            'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
    }
).then(function (result) {
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(result);
}, function(error) {
    console.log('Error:');
    console.log(error);
});
```

Lets break this down: Url is a little obvious, so we skip that...

1. data: This is the body content of your postman request

   ```
   {
       Description: 'Test Object',
       TestType: 'PostTest'
   }
   ```
2. config: This is where we can inject headers, event handlers, caching... see [AngularJS: API: $http: scroll down to config](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) Headers are the most common postman variant of http that people struggle to replicate in angularJS

   ```
   {
       headers {
           'Authorization': 'Basic d2VudHdvcnRobWFuOkNoYW5nZV9tZQ==',
           'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
       }
   }
   ```
3. Response: the $http actions return an angular promise, I recommend using .then(successFunction, errorFunction) to process that promise see [AngularJS: The Deferred API (Promises)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

   ```
   .then(function (result) {
       console.log('Success');
       console.log(result);
   }, function(error) {
       console.log('Error:');
       console.log(error);
   });
   ```