# Unable to send data using POST request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, post

I try to post data from angularJS to my web-Service and want to get data back.

The post-request works great, I get data back (which I hardcoded in PHP), but (after 2h searching) my problem is that I cant send some Post-Data.

Here my code:

```
   angular.module('LunchApp', [])
  .controller('MessagesCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        var postData = { callMethod: 'getChat' };
        $http.post(url, postData).success(function(data){
            $scope.messages = data;
        });
  });
```

I have tried many solutions:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs-egO-odAg
- [How do I POST urlencoded form data with $http in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24710503/how-do-i-post-urlencoded-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs)
- [$http post in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894650/http-post-in-angular-js)

but nothing works for me... :(

If I try it with a RESTful TestClient, it works perfectly. all posted data reach the server. But not with AngularJS :(

Comment: Did you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442632/how-can-i-post-data-as-form-data-instead-of-a-request-payload

Comment: Is your variable "postData" in the format expected by $http.post function?

Comment: oh my god... $.param(); is the solution. thank you so much!