# move a file from the client-side to the server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, upload

I have an html upload form and an angular controller controlling it. In the controller, I found out how to get the files uploaded but my question is how can I move/upload these files to the server? I checked out multer but I don't believe this is going to work in my case because I can't require it in the client-side. Here is what my controller currently looks like:

```
  app.controller('uploadCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http){

  $scope.enableSubmitButton = false;
  $scope.fileSizeError = false;
  var selectedFiles = [];

  //get files selected
  $scope.getFiles = function($files){

    selectedFiles = $files;

    //display upload button if there is a valid file to upload
    if(selectedFiles.length !== 0){
      $scope.enableSubmitButton = true;
    }

  }

  $scope.upload = function(){

    if($scope.enableSubmitButton){

      //disable to prevent clicking again
      $scope.enableSubmitButton = false;

      //correctly shows the file data
      console.dir(selectedFiles);


     //upload files to server
     //What should I do here?

    }

  }

});
```

Comment: it's hard to say what `selectedFiles` contains but what you want to be looking for is the `$http` service from angular

Comment: selectedFiles is an array of files. I did look at the $http service but I can't figure out how to make a post request with files (if that is even what I should do).

Comment: the http service has a `post` method that you would want to use (since you are posting files). if you need a callback you can chain the post function with a `success` or `then`. perhaps [this question and it's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894650/http-post-in-angular-js) may help?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example

**Step:1** Initialize Your app

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

**Step:2**  Make a directive named `fileModel`. it can use link funtion and bind `change` property so that if a file upload, change function executes 
and then set `model scope` with files object.simple it parses file object

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
                return {
                   restrict: 'A', //define attribute 
                   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                      var modelSetter = model.assign;

                      element.bind('change', function(){
                         scope.$apply(function(){
                            modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                         });
                      });
                   }
                };
             }]);
```

**Step:3** Make a fileUpload `service` so that transfer file to server using `$http`

```
 myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
            this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
               var fd = new FormData(); //FormData
               fd.append('file', file); //file object 

               $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} //define req headers
               })

               .success(function(){

               })

               .error(function(){
               });
            }
         }]);
```

**Step:4** use `fileUpload service` and call its `uploadFileToUrl` function and pass file object and url for

```
 myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){        //uploadFile function
                $scope.uploadFile = function(){
                   var file = $scope.myFile;

                   console.log('file is ' );
                   console.dir(file);

                   var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
                   fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
                };
             }]);
```

Comment: I saw almost that exact code somewhere on SO but I didn't understand it. Would you mind explaining what is happening?